# How to set next enable date as default date in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have checked so many questions on stackoverflow but didn't get any relevent answer to my problem.

Here i am checking query parameter  and disabling weekends. 
now

**if today is Friday then I want Monday as a selected (default date)** weekends.
Since I already have written code to disable

```
if (valueofquerrystring == mobility) 
{
             var datemob = new Date(); var mmob = date.getMonth(), dmob = date.getDate(),     ymob     = date.getFullYear();
            $('#SelectedDate').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(y, m, d), dateFormat: 'mm-dd-     yy', beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
            });enter code here


    //hiding radiobuttons
            $("#afternoon").hide();
            $("#evening").hide();
            $("#morningMobility").attr('checked', true);
        }
        else {

            $("#morningMobility").hide();
            $("#afternoon").show();
            $("#evening").show();
}
```

any help will be appreciated regarding this.

Comment: can you please tell us in which language you are trying to do this task, as **Language Tag is must to get help from SO**, even I can't understand this code.

Comment: @Nisha Thankyou for suggesting relevent Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set default date in two ways

**1. if you want to set Today is default date:**

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
// Or on the init
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
```

**2. if your want to set 3 days from today: (Ex. If Today is FRIDAY then set MONDAY as default)**

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", 3);
// Or on the init
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: 3 });
```